# Can 'on one occasion' and 'at 5am' be called sentence connectors /conjunctive adverbs?

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

In the given examples:

1. He never invited anyone. On one occasion, somebody came.

Does "on one occasion" act as sentence connector here acting as conjunctive adverb?

2. He has a tight schedule. At 5 am,  he starts his day.

Is "at 5 am" a sentence connector acting like conjunctive adverb?

Thanks